# DYMO 450 Label Printing with JS printing framework won't detect the printer after several page refresh

Tags: javascript, printing, dymo

I have used [DYMO Web Service Beta Installer Beta 2](http://www.labelwriter.com/SDK_Beta/DYMO.Label.Framework_2.0Beta2.js) to print labels from my web app to a dymo label printer.

With the initial page load of the print module it works perfectly. But when I go to another webpage then go back to the print module or refreshing the webpage I get this error when I try to print again. [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKNyi.png)

I have updated my dymo's software driver hoping that it would fix this issue but it did not.

EDIT: updated links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the source of the problem: [article](http://developers.dymo.com/2017/12/12/err_ssl_version_interference-in-chrome-63-using-the-js-sdk/). I TLS 1.3 and it works. I hope they would fix their framework soon.